# How to theme gnome.shell calendar panel button

Tags: gnome-shell, css

I was trying to change the theme of panel button : calendar
And here is my attempt
[image]

I need to make calendar looks like this, specifically how to alter the appearance of the first line or second line in StLabel
..

### CSS class name :

`#panel .panel-button StLabel`

[image]

version: 18.10
theme: arc-dark gnome shell theme

Comment: what is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: first line and second line you are talking about is 12:31 and Tue, 25. Dec??

Comment: yes, exactly those are the lines

Comment: are you using clock override extension? in simple you want first line font-size and second line font-size to be customized rite?

Comment: yes I use them, just to override how they appear ... I use this format :
`      %H:%M%n%a, %d. %h`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The style_class for this particular field is `#panel .clock-display`

examples:

```
#panel .clock-display { color: yellow; text-align: center; font-size: 11pt; }
```

[image]

```
#panel .clock-display { color: yellow; text-align: center; font-size: 20pt; }
```

[image]

```
#panel .clock-display { color: magenta; text-align: center; font-size: 10pt; }
```

[image]

In my opinion and after several attempts,

since 1st line & 2nd line are from `Clock Override` Extension..
the alteration you are looking for 1st line & 2nd line is not possible unless this extension or gnome-shell system files are edited to match to separate those two lines.

Comment: I want the selector class of first and second line in the calendar button .. I'm using arc-dark gnome shell theme

Answer (score 1):

careful if you are using the Unite Gnome Tweak as it's first button in its preferences stops top bar css file changes

```
super key
type TWEAK
select Unite
select Extension Settings
unselect the "apply system fonts to shell theme"
restart xorg alt F2, r, enter
```

the last was not necessary as I had already done that with the css edit. results were immediate.

my editing of my theme's gnome.shell.css (yaru theme Ubuntu 19.04) file did not work until I unchecked the tweak